# How can I understand this python error message?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi can you help me decode this message and what to do:

```
main.py", line 1278, in post
    message.body = "%s %s/%s/%s" % (msg, host, ad.key().id(), slugify(ad.title.encode('utf-8')))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thanks

UPDATE having tried removing the encode call it appears to work:

```
class Recommend(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, key):
        ad= db.get(db.Key(key))
        email = self.request.POST['tip_email']     
        host = os.environ.get("HTTP_HOST", os.environ["SERVER_NAME"])
        senderemail = users.get_current_user().email() if users.get_current_user() else 'info@monton.cl' if host.endswith('.cl') else 'info@monton.com.mx' if host.endswith('.mx') else 'info@montao.com.br' if host.endswith('.br') else 'admin@koolbusiness.com'
        message = mail.EmailMessage(sender=senderemail, subject="%s recommends %s" % (self.request.POST['tip_name'], ad.title) )
        message.to = email
        message.body = "%s %s/%s/%s" % (self.request.POST['tip_msg'],host,ad.key().id(),slugify(ad.title))
        message.send()
        matched_images=ad.matched_images
        count = matched_images.count()
        if ad.text:
            p = re.compile(r'(www[^ ]*|http://[^ ]*)')
            text = p.sub(r'<a href="http://\1" rel="nofollow">\1</a>',ad.text.replace('http://',''))
        else:
            text = None
        self.response.out.write("Message sent<br>")
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'market', 'market_ad_detail.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'user_url':users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if users.get_current_user() else users.create_login_url(self.request.uri),
        'user':users.get_current_user(), 'ad.user':ad.user,'count':count, 'ad':ad, 'matched_images': matched_images,}))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588083/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa3)

Comment: if you search on SO for that error, you get pages and pages and pages and pages and pages and pages of questions and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your underlying model (message.body) only wants ASCII text but you're trying to give it a string encoded in unicode.

But since you've got a normal ascii string here, you can just make python print out the '?' character when you've got a non-ascii-printing string.

```
"UNICODE STRING".encode('ascii','replace').decode('ascii')
```

So like from your example above:

```
message.body = "%s %s/%s/%s" % \
     (msgencode('ascii','replace').decode('ascii'),
     hostencode('ascii','replace').decode('ascii'),
     ad.key().id()encode('ascii','replace').decode('ascii'),
     slugify(ad.title)encode('ascii','replace').decode('ascii'))
```

Or just encode/decode on the variable that has the unicode character.

But this isn't an optimal solution.  The best idea is to make message.body a unicode string. Being that doesn't seem feasible (I'm not familiar with GAE), you can use this to at least not have errors.

Comment: OK! I do it. Thanks a lot for investigating it.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly feasible - just use a db.StringProperty or db.TextProperty. You really, really shouldn't just replace all unicode characters with question marks - we live in the 20th century. People use unicode.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a Unicode character in a place that you're not supposed to.  Most often I find this error is having MS Word-style slanted quotes.

Answer (score 1):

One of these fields has some characters that cannot be encoded. If you switch to python 3 (it has better unicode support), or you change the encoding of the entire script the problem should stop, about the best way to change the encoding in 2.x is using the encoding comment line. If you see http://evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html you will see more of an explanation of using python with utf-8 support the best suggestion is add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your script. And handle scripts like this

```
s = "hello normal string"
u = unicode( s, "utf-8" )
backToBytes = u.encode( "utf-8" )
```

Comment: Sadly, GAE [doesn't support Python 3](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=909).

Comment: I noticed the GAE in question but I didn't want to change my answer.

Comment: It's fairly unlikely the unicode character is actually in the source code, so setting the encoding for the source file will be absolutely nothing to help. The issue is almost certainly caused by taking utf-8 input from a user and sticking it into a `str` rather than coercing it to a `unicode`.

Comment: There is no solution. I tried everything and redeployed so many versions getting the same error that this really stinks calling python a high-level language and now this.

Comment: Wooble, I also try following the info you posted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using Django norel and Google App Engine.

The problem was at the folder containing the application. Probably isn't this the problem described in this question, but, maybe helps someone don't waste time like me.

Try first change you application folder maybe to /home/ and try to run again, if doesn't works, try something more.